# Which IP address is valid or not

Tags: tcp

im: Given an IPv4 classful address string, implement a program to validate if it is an IPv4 address
or not.
Theory: Points to be remembered as rules to validate IPv4 address string:

1. No leading zeros should be accepted in the string.
2. Range of decimal values for IP address should be within 0 to 255.
3. IPv4 address string should have exactly 4 cells.
4. The cell value should have an INTEGER value only. No other values or BLANK SPACES
   should be accepted from user.
5. The decimal values should be separated by dot(.) only.
6. Error messages should be displayed for wrong entry in the program.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question. Only a list of items and no problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static bool IsValidIPAddress(string IPAddress)
{
    try
    {
    string[] AddressParts = IPAddress.Replace(" ", "").Split(Convert.ToChar("."));

    if(AddressParts.Length != 4)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < AddressParts.Length; i++)
    {
        if(Convert.ToInt16(AddressParts[i]) < 0 || Convert.ToInt16(AddressParts[i]) > 255)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```